Can I block programs from preventing sleep?
Ever since I "upgraded" to Sonoma, I've had occasional, severe battery drain when my MacBook should be sleeping or hibernating. I'm now running the latest, Sonoma 14.4.1. My battery drains way too far. Here's an example:

I ran pmset -g log and discovered this, which suggests Skype prevented sleep for around five hours! Note the battery level on the first and last lines here:
2024-04-24 01:44:23 -0400 Assertions            Summary- [System: No Assertions] Using Batt(Charge: 85)          
2024-04-24 03:45:26 -0400 Assertions            PID 75061(Skype) Created PreventSystemSleep "Preparing update" 00:00:00  id:0x0x70000a5b0 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-04-24 03:45:26 -0400 Assertions            PID 75061(Skype) Released PreventSystemSleep "Preparing update" 00:00:00  id:0x0x70000a5b0 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-04-24 04:58:09 -0400 Assertions            PID 114(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a654 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-04-24 04:58:14 -0400 Assertions            PID 114(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd0000a654 [System: No Assertions]          
2024-04-24 06:32:13 -0400 Assertions            PID 114(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 20 seconds to query model for inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a72f [System: SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2024-04-24 06:32:13 -0400 Assertions            PID 114(powerd) Released InternalPreventSleep "Holding in darkwake for up to 20 seconds to query model for inactivity prediction" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a72f [System: No Assertions]          
2024-04-24 06:32:13 -0400 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Sleep Service Back to Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=disabled Using Batt (Charge:17%) 3667 secs 

Is there some way to block programs from preventing sleep, especially while my MacBook should be asleep?

Update: after quitting Skype and putting the laptop to sleep hours earlier, I came back to a hot, closed-lid laptop this afternoon. According to the log, the battery was dropping about 2% every 5 minutes. What causes this?!


As an analysis step, does the situation improve if you quit Skype (including all its background jobs) before putting the laptop to sleep?

Also, if I read the pmset -g log correctly, Skype wanted to install an update. Did you check whether this was successful?

I added an update to my question that seems to take Skype out of the equation because I had quit the app. I suppose I could look for an update time in Skype’s “about” window.

Activity Monitor has an "Energy" tab, which applications are on top there?

The problem hasn't happened again since you asked, but Firefox has the highest energy impact, at 11 of whatever units, which seems reasonable to me.

It seems as if there is a bug in Sonoma because I would expect the Macbook to hibernate below a certain power level and stop wrecking my battery.

Also, when I started Skype for the first time since the problem, it prompted me for an admin password to install some helper. After installing that, it won't tell me when the latest update happened, just that Im on the latest version.
